# Move keyboard cursor position to base character from superscript in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, superscript

I have a div with both normal and superscript characters using the tag sup and after entering text in the `<sup>` tag, the keyboard caret doesn't move to the baseline so I'm unable to enter normal characters again. Is there any way to move the cursor from power to base?

Example: "X<sup>y</sup>"

Xʸ, after entering y, the cursor stays at top and whatever I enter after that is superscript and I want to be able to type normal characters after entering superscript, how to move the cursor down.

Comment: Im not really sure what you mean, but could pressing the right arrow be what you're looking for? Most editors work like that

Comment: @Martijn  When I press the right arrow in the div, cursor remains in the power position and not in base so everything I type is small, I want cursor to move to base.

Comment: What editor are you using? Try shift+tab